# Wordpress multisites main domain redirecting fails

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I have done multisite installation and also created wildcard subdomain. When i type the domain with www the website redirected successfully. However, when i type the domain WITHOUT www, the page gets failed and says no url found. Pls help me with this issue. I am trying hard to get this one success from yesterday.

I have provided the code given in installation to replace in .htaccess file.

Comment: Hi! The main domain is registered with WWW or without WWW? Also, I can't see any .htaccess code.

Comment: Main domain is with www. Below is the existing .htaccess code 
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a big hurry. Code for redirecting from non-www to wwww is the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Add it at the beginning of the file.